# Cshtml inserting space inside title tag

Tags: c#, razor

I have this code in a simple view:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" @(check==true ? "title=\"Press Here\"" : "") />
```

The title tag should be displayed if check is true but on the view itself I only get "Press" without the second word " Here". looking at developer tools and inspecting it shows the " Here" has moved outside the title tag quotes. trying to manipulate it using " or "" with no luck of escaping the space between the words. Any idea anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline simply, something like this should works:

```
title="@(check == true ? "Press Here" : string.Empty)"
```